# Dropdown value selected using ng-selected expression in angular js on page load

Tags: angularjs

This is my code

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.searchButtonText = [
            { label: 'test1' },
            { label: 'test2' },
            { label: 'test3' },
            { label: 'test4' },
            { label: 'test5' },
            { label: 'test6' }
        ];
    });
```

This is my view

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <select name="Default" ng-model="default" ng-selected="data.label=='test4'" ng-options="data as data.label for data in searchButtonText" ></select>
</div>
```

Here I got the Select box with options successfully, but I actually need to select the option by default on page load with expression mentioned in below.

Please help me,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should try like as below

**Option - 1.**

```
scope.searchButtonText = [
        { label: 'test1' },
        { label: 'test2' },
        { label: 'test3' },
        { label: 'test4' },
        { label: 'test5' },
        { label: 'test6' }
    ];
```

Assign your model

```
$scope.default = $scope.searchButtonText[3];
```

**Option - 2**

```
<select name="Default" ng-model="default" ng-selected="default=searchButtonText[3]" ng-options="data as data.label for data in searchButtonText" >Test</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

```
<select name="Default"
        ng-init="default = searchButtonText[3]" 
        ng-model="default" 
        ng-options="data as data.label for data in searchButtonText">
</select>
```